# How do I create multi-line tabulations in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, tabs

I have Microsoft Word 2007 document:[image]

However you can see with longer word it doesn't go like I want, it would be better if it would spawn a new line like in another example below (I made it but formatting looks weird with that shift enter and I think it's possible to make it other way)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have invented [tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-or-create-a-table-HA010034300.aspx#BM1) for this purpose.

Don't do this manually, it'll be a pain to manage it and you don't want special characters shown for that...

Comment: Table are certainly the easy way to go

Comment: yeah I guess I could but better would be with tabs and it's just for one word, but if it's really very very hard to make then I will just increase first tab length, because it's just a bit longer word

Comment: The only exception is the last term can be made to wrap by setting the hanging indent to the position of the last tab stop.

Comment: @Templar: Tabs aren't meant to made columns of wrapping text. Similar to Tables, you can also introduce [Columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-layout-or-formatting-in-one-section-of-your-document-HP001226502.aspx) into your document, if that's what you want. As said, don't do this kind of stuff manually as you'll lose a great deal of time trying to get something perfect which can happen automatically through Tables or Columns...

Comment: Can you also look this question? http://superuser.com/questions/338244/how-to-make-something-like-that-with-columns-in-ms-word-07