# How to make something like that with columns in MS Word 07

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, text-formatting

It's following after this question: [How do I create multi-line tabulations in Microsoft Word 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/337962/how-do-i-create-multi-line-tabulations-in-microsoft-word-2007)

I was told that I should make it with tables or columns. Yes I can make with tables but will it be possible to make something like that with columns?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns are meant for newspaper-like documents, where you often see multiple columns of text.

---

For what you want, you can make a table that looks like this:

```
|----------------------------|
| Very very long word        |
|--------------|-------------|
| First word   | second      |
|              | third       |
|--------------|-------------|
| Again very very long word  |
|----------------------------|
| Fourth word  | fifth       |
|----------------------------|
```

Word allows you to remove edges from tables, so start of a table with 4 rows and 2 columns.

You can also select the whole table and then remove the borders, so it looks like in your screenshot.

If anything is not clear, let us know...